# SwiftUI how to manually add a system back button in root view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a hybrid app with both UIKit and SwiftUI. The root VC is UINavController in UIKit, and I present `UIHostingController` to host a SwiftUI feature. The SwiftUI has its own `NavigationStack`, so I hide the UIKit nav bar in `UIHostingController`, so that there's only 1 nav bar:

```
class MyHostingVC: UIHostingController<AnyView> {
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // hide the UIKit's nav bar, so that we only show SwiftUI's nav bar
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
  }
}
```

Now in SwiftUI's root view, it doesn't have a back button, because to SwiftUI, the root view is the root, and it doesn't know the fact that UIHostingController is presented by UIKit's nav controller.

I could easily add a button to top left corner like this:

```
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    ...


      .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
          Button("Back") {
            dismiss()
          }
        }
      }
```

What's surprisingly good is that `dismiss()` actually works - it pop's the whole `UIHostingController` and returns to my UIKit screens.

I can even add an arrow to the left of the "Back" label, so it looks like the system back button. However, I would have to do localization for all languages. Also, for RTL languages, I would have to flip the arrow direction, and put arrow to the right of the "Back" label. So pretty tedious to do.

Is there a better way to force showing the system back button?

Comment: The placement of the button is already handled by `navigationBarLeading`, and if you use the correct SF symbol, the direction of the arrow changes automatically too. That only leaves localisation of the text, which is only one extra text you have to localise. Note that you only have to do localisations for the languages your app support, not every language *in the world*. If you are already translating all the other text in the app, translating an extra "Back" isn't too much extra work.

Comment: I would suggest doing the opposite. Hiding the SwiftUI navigation and showing the UIKit one, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77289766/14294561

Comment: @narek.sv I can't hide the SwiftUI nav, because I want the nav bar to be controlled by SwiftUI code (e.g. what buttons to show on nav bar). `.toolbar` with a custom View doesn't work on UIKit nav bar.

Comment: for some context, i used to use the uikit nav bar with no problem because the (deprecated) NavigationView API can reuse the uikit nav bar (e.g. `toolbar { Text }` actually put a text in uikit nav bar). However, the new NavigationStack API doesn't re-use uikit nav bar anymore. You can find more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77588535/swiftuis-new-navigationstack-api-doesnt-work-well-with-uihostingcontrollers-n

Comment: @Sweeper when i add the swipe gesture to pop the nav stack, i noticed that the system back button has extra animation, that slowly decreases the opacity, and the "Back" label and the arrow also animates away from each other a bit. The custom button doesn't behave that way (or at least without lots of efforts)